# How to write a command in eclipse to clean project?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I want to write a command to clean the c/c++ project. I know to make a command extending the org.eclipse.ui.menus. But how to implement the clean project ? I know there is **org.eclipse.ui.project.cleanAction** action but it opens up the dialog to choose whether clean selected project or clean all projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the code in **org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.CleanDialog** class. By default CleanDialog loads all projects present inside the workspace and automatically select all projects which were selected in project explorer view. You can filter only C/C++ projects by modifying the code inside createProjectSelectionTable method(See line no 272 projectNames.addFilter) as shown below

```
if(!project.hasNature("org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature") //For c projects || !project.hasNature("org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature") // For c++ projects) {
    return false;
}
```

If you want to avoid opening CleanDialog then re-use code present inside buttonPressed method.